# Python gsl_vector_set

Tags: python, ctypes, gsl

I'm trying to initialize two vectors in memory using gsl_vector_set(). In the main code it is initialized to zero on default, but I wanted to initialize them to some non-zero value. I made a test code based on a working function that uses the gsl_vector_set() function.

```
from ctypes import *;

gsl = cdll.LoadLibrary('libgsl-0.dll');
gsl.gsl_vector_get.restype = c_double;
gsl.gsl_matrix_get.restype = c_double;
gsl.gsl_vector_set.restype = c_double;

foo = dict(
    x_ht = [0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,
            0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0],
    x_ht_m = [0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,
              0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]
    );
for f in range(0,18):
    gsl.gsl_vector_set(foo['x_ht_m'],f,c_double(1.0));
    gsl.gsl_vector_set(foo['x_ht'],f,c_double(1.0));
```

When I run the code I get this error.

```
ArgumentError: argument 1: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: Don't know how to convert parameter 1
```

I'm new to using ctypes and gsl functions so I'm not sure what the issue is or what the error message means. I an also not sure if there is a better way that I should be trying to save a vector to memory

Comment: Things aren't so simple. First you'd have to define the `gsl_vector` type (using `ctypes.Structure`) and all the custom inner types (e.g. `gsl_block`), then create one (via e.g.: `gsl_vector_alloc`). And for all functions involved, you'll have to also define their `argtypes`. I don't have *libgsl* installed, and I'd avoid posting code without running it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @CristiFati for pointing out that I needed gsl_vector_calloc in my test code. I noticed that in the main code I was working in that the vector I needed to set was

```
NAV.KF_dictnry['x_hat_m']
```

instead of

```
NAV.KF_dictnry['x_ht_m']
```

So I fixed the test code to mirror the real code a bit better by creating a class holding the dictionary, and added the ability to change each value in the vector to an arbitrary value.

```
from ctypes import *;
gsl = cdll.LoadLibrary('libgsl-0.dll');
gsl.gsl_vector_get.restype = c_double;
gsl.gsl_matrix_get.restype = c_double;
gsl.gsl_vector_set.restype = c_double;
class foo(object):
    fu = dict(
        x_hat = gsl.gsl_vector_calloc(c_size_t(18)),
        x_hat_m = gsl.gsl_vector_calloc(c_size_t(18)),
        );
x_ht = [1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,
        1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0]
x_ht_m = [1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,
          1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0]
for f in range(0,18):
    gsl.gsl_vector_set(foo.fu['x_hat_m'],f,c_double(x_ht_m[f]));
    gsl.gsl_vector_set(foo.fu['x_hat'],f,c_double(x_ht[f]));
```

After running I checked with:

```
gsl.gsl_vector_get(foo.fu['x_hat_m'],0)
```

and got out a 1.0 (worked for the entire vector).

Turned out to just be some stupid mistakes on my end.

Thanks again!